# brew: Failed to set filetime 1503098583 on outfile: errno 1

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, homebrew

I see now often a new error when invoking brew. It works anyway, but I wonder how to fix `Failed to set filetime on outfile: errno 1`

```
brew install redis                      
Failed to set filetime 1503098583 on outfile: errno 1          
Failed to set filetime 1500719840 on outfile: errno 1          
Failed to set filetime 1503105755 on outfile: errno 1          
Failed to set filetime 1503098357 on outfile: errno 1          
Failed to set filetime 1503115442 on outfile: errno 1          
Failed to set filetime 1499154411 on outfile: errno 1          
Updating Homebrew...           
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!     
Updated 3 taps (caskroom/cask, cloudfoundry/tap, homebrew/core).                                                               
==> New Formulae
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, and similar situation as others via Github Homebrew/brew [#issue 2921](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/2921#issuecomment-317174254).

It was the "**remote-time**" line from my `~/.curlrc` file.

To fix it, just comment out the line with a `#` like:

```
#remote-time
```